# Output 300 png images with correct filenames from svg or svg via canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, png

For browsers that don't support SVG, I'd like to show a static image of a chart instead of an interactive version.

One idea is to generate all possible chart states (around 300) beforehand. I tried using the Canvas2Image library but it doesn't seem to allow me to specify a filename. Is there any workaround? Perhaps a server-side solution?

Comment: You want to use a web browser with SVG support to generate all possible images and then put them on the server to serve them statically?

Comment: A quite ugly solution might be to combine some JavaScript zip implementation like [jszip](http://stuartk.com/jszip/) and Canvas2Image. That way you can specify the images names but maybe not the zip file itself, but that might not be needed.

Comment: @MattiasWadman: Yes, I decided to send the Canvas2Image png string to PHP together with a filename.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple other ways to solve this.

`rsvg` is a rendering library that processes SVGs statically single-pass.  It's used in ImageMagick's convert tool, and also has python and other bindings.  Some people find various SVG-isms aren't supported, but rsvg gets updates now and then so best to just try and see.

`inkscape` is a GUI program that includes SVG->PNG conversion.  But it can also be used exclusively on the command line (no X11 required).  See `man inkscape` for all the command line options that can be used to process your svg's; it's quite flexible.  The rendering is relatively fast.  The main downside is that being a GUI program it has a lot of dependencies, that might not be present on a web server.